# Why don't more C programs embed Perl?

Tags: c, perl

I know there is a way to call Perl routines from C. As shown here
http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perlcall.pod#NAME

But, still I do not see a widespread use of this by C programmers. Has any one used this ...ever? or any idea what are the reasons that it is not used so much?

Comment: Because C programmers are 'real programmers'. They don't need no steenkin' perl. :)

Comment: Now lets not be disrespectful to Perl....there is some really good good stuff written in Perl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the most well known example of a C program embedding perl is [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) and [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org), which lets people access the Apache API through Perl.

You probably don't see many programs embedding perl because they don't need it as a feature. Why don't more C programs send email? :)

Comment: The full version of vim also embeds Perl.  The :perldo command is occasionally useful.

Answer (score 7):

Its usually done in reverse.  That is, the scripting language coordinates things, and the C program does the processing.
The idea is that the code that coordinates is easy to modify, and the code that does the processing runs fast.

The thing to do would probably be to spawn the perl interpreter via the "system" call from C to do something.  Probably not quite what you have in mind though.

Comment: Not exactly....but still I have a question for some one who has actually used this intensively....what about performance....?

Comment: Performance will be similar to calling the same functions from Perl itself. It will be slower than doing the same in C, but by much and if that's acceptable depends entirely on the problem you're trying to fix.

Comment: I agree, performance won't be good.  But if you have C code, and care about performance, you probably won't be calling Perl.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons why one may call a perl function from C: extending and embedding.

In the former case, it isn't all that uncommon actually, but it's rather invisible for outsiders.

What I think your question really is though is *"why don't people embed perl more often?"* There are a number of reasons for that, it being far more difficult than it should be is the most important one IMHO (see [perlcall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html), [perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html), [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) and [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Why would I slow down my C program by calling Perl?  And I say that as a [confirmed Perler](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+user%3A78259).  Now, calling into C from Perl, that makes sense (if you need the extra speed).

When one develops in C, it is because they want to trade development time for execution speed.

When one develops in Perl, it is because they want to trade execution speed for development time.

Comment: You are on to something here -- nobody writes programs that need to "glue" things together in C.  It is not good for that.

Answer (score 2):

One situation where this is used is in a plug-in or scripting architecture. For example, the [irssi](http://irssi.org/) IRC client is written in C but supports [scripting with Perl](http://irssi.org/documentation/perl).

In my experience however, building irssi with Perl enabled is troublesome and prone to failure. I have had instances where the program wouldn't build at all with Perl bindings enabled (some compile or link failure), and also where the program would compile but would immediately fail on startup with a runtime error. These sorts of problems might explain why it's not terribly popular—calling one language from another is almost never as easy as it is in .Net.

Comment: Yep..I agree with you that it is not easy to integrate Perl with C.

Comment: Interestingly, it is easy other way - to integrate C from Perl. You can do it with XS or Inline::C.
As for general language interoperability, you can do it in Parrot. But languages based on Parrot are not finished yet.

Answer (score -1):

Many programmers know how to obfuscate C very effectively, without needing to resort to Perl.

Comment: guess I shouldn't tell jokes in church